# python ultrajson: how to use?

Tags: python, json

I've just installed ultrajson (ujson) to see if I can't get the json decoding to go faster (string to object). However, I'm not seeing any examples of how to use it.

with regular json it's just

```
import json
my_object = json.loads(my_string)
```

Comment: It's pretty much a drop in replacement: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson

Comment: Cool, don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Change the import statement to `import ujson as json`

Then you can leave the other parts of your program as it is.

Comment: Would this also be the same for `simplejson`?